# Python Join, Concat string elements from two lists to make a new list

Tags: python, list, loops

I want to create a new list from elements of two lists as below:

Given:

```
x = ["a","b"]
y = [".c",".d"]
```

Get:

```
z = ["a.c","a.d","b.c","b.d"]
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```py
x = ["a","b"]
y = [".c",".d"]

z = [xx + yy for xx in x for yy in y]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
z = [''.join((letter1, letter2)) for letter1 in x for letter2 in y]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from itertools import product
x = ["a","b"]
y = [".c",".d"]
z = [l + r for l, r in product(x, y)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply using `+` operator

```
x = ["a","b"]
y = [".c",".d"]

z = x + y
```

`z` is equals to `['a', 'b', '.c', '.d']`